# bodyparser error with mongoose mongodb nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Am merging 2 different applications one is an authentification app and the other is a todo app where user input data and the app displays it. The two work fine seperately. when i merged them there is a parse error on the second app; I think i got the issue. the authentification app uses app.use(bodyParser.json()); and the second one uses app.use(bodyParser()); I think there is a conflict but i dont know how to solve it can you help

here is my api

```
var Meetup = require('./models/meetup');



module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var meetup = new Meetup(req.body);
  console.log(req.body);
  meetup.save(function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result);
  });
}

module.exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Meetup.find({}, function (err, results) {
    res.json(results);
  });
}
```

console.log(req.body) displays undefined.
console.log(result) displays { __v: 0, _id: 583464c837cb810e045b1825 } while it should display { __v: 0,name:'text input' _id: 583464c837cb810e045b1825 }

here is my schema model :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Meetup = new Schema({
  name: String,
  text:String,

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Meetup', Meetup);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `bodyParser()` constructor is [deprecated](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/commit/b7420f8dc5c8b17a277c9e50d72bbaf3086a3900).

You should use this instead:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```